# spring-boot - how to specify path of application.properties in envrionment or system properties?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

If I want to run spring boot application, and want to use difference application.properties in difference path (other than using profile)

How can I specify path for `application.properties`?

Comment: `--spring.config.location=file:/{path}/application.properties`

Comment: @kzharas210 that should be -Dspring.config.location=

FYI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use difference application.properties in difference path, use this command to start the jar file

```
nohup java -jar project.jar --spring.config.location=file://{file-path}/application.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

environment variable `SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION` can be also used.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

@PropertySource annotation is used to provide properties file into the environment and it is used with @Configuration classes.

@PropertySource({ "classpath:config.properties" })

Answer (score 0):

use bellow code above main class:

```
@PropertySource(value = {"file:///${HOMEDIR}/application.properties"})
```